# why schema clear() and schema creation are taking so long in Datastax DSE 5.0.x Graph?

Tags: datastax, datastax-enterprise, gremlin, datastax-enterprise-graph

I have a graph that has no data in it. Yet schema.clear() takes more than 3-4 minutes to execute. schema creation takes another 2 mins.. Is this normal or there is something wrong with my configuration?

Thanks!

Comment: Generally it should not take that much long, though it depends upon your size and complexity of schema and of course your connection strength.

Comment: @Piyush_Rana we are talking about less than 20 vertex types and 10 edge types - on local ethernet network with less than 100 vertices and edges stored or empty on a dual core lenovo think server of 2015 running a single instance of DSE on ubuntu